# Find minimum value of $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, geometric-inequalities, jensen-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

If $a,b,c$ are sides of triangle Find Minimum value of

$$S=\sum \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}$$

My Try:

Let $$P=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$$

we have $$S=\sum \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{a}}-1}$$

$$S=\sum \frac{1}{\frac{P}{\sqrt{a}}-2}$$

Let $x=\frac{P}{\sqrt{a}}$, $y=\frac{P}{\sqrt{b}}$,$z=\frac{P}{\sqrt{c}}$

Then we have $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=1$$

By $AM \ge HM$

$$\frac{x+y+z}{3} \ge \frac{3}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}}$$

Hence

$$x+y+z \ge 9$$

Any way to proceed further?

Comment: Is this sum cyclic in $a,b,c$?

Comment: Yes it is a cyclic expression

Comment: You can assume that one of the variables is 1.

Comment: Now why is the question  voted to close as off topic? Any reason by the person who voted it to close?

Comment: When you say “minimum value,” what are you allowing to vary? A trivial solution is anything where the sides approach length $0$ but that’s not what you want I presume.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Don't you think the value obtained when the triangle is equilateral would be the minimum. Try substituting the values for a, b, c.  As these values of a, b, c vary, the summation takes on a different value . we need the condition as well as the minimum value which the summation can take as we change the lengths of sides with respect to each other. And if the lengths approach 0 we will get a term approaching $\frac {0}{0}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $a = b = c$, $S = 3$. Next it will be proved that $S \geqslant 3$ for all possible $a, b, c$.

Denote $\displaystyle u = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c}}$, $\displaystyle v = \frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c}}$, $\displaystyle w = \frac{\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c}}$, then $\sum u = 1$. Since$$
\sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b + c} < \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c},
$$
then $\displaystyle 0 < u < \frac{1}{2}$. Analogously, $\displaystyle 0 < v, w < \frac{1}{2}$. It suffices to prove$$
S = \sum \frac{u}{v + w - u} = \sum \frac{u}{1 - 2u} \geqslant 3.
$$

Define $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x}{1 - 2x} \ (0 < x < \frac{1}{2})$. Because $\displaystyle f''(x) = \frac{4}{(1 - 2x)^3} > 0$, by Jensen's inequality,$$
S = \sum f(u) \geqslant 3 f\left(\frac{1}{3} \sum u\right) = 3f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) = 3.
$$
Therefore the minimum of $S$ is $3$.

Answer (score 6):

I did the following:

Let $x=\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}$, $y=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{b}$ and $z=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c}$. Then $\frac{x+y}{2}=\sqrt{c}, \frac{x+z}{2}=\sqrt{b}$ and $\frac{y+z}{2}=\sqrt{a}$. Rewriting the original expression, we get $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y+z}{x}+\frac{x+z}{y}+\frac{x+y}{z}\right)$$

It is easy to see that this expression is greater than or equal to $3$, as $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\geq 2$ by AM-GM inequality.

This minimum value is achieved when $a=b=c$

Answer (score 5):

$$\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}=\sqrt{b+c+2\sqrt{bc}}>\sqrt{b+c}>\sqrt{a},$$
which says that all denominators are positives.

Now, by C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}-a}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}-a)}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+2\sqrt{ab})}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2\sqrt{ab}-a)}\geq3$$
because the last inequality it's just $$\sum_{cyc}(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2\geq0.$$

The equality occurs for $a=b=c$, which says that $3$ is a minimal value.

We can use also the Rearrangement.

Indeed, the triples $(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c})$ and $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{b}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c}}\right)$ are the same ordered.

Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}\right)=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}$$ and we are done again.

Another way:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}-3=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}-1\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}-(\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a})}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}=\sum_{cyc}(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}\right)=$$
$$=2\sum_{cyc}\frac{(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2}{(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a})(\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})}\geq0.$$